# Don't work require in Copmposer

Tags: composer-php

I have composer.json on project:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.test.ua:bmp/composer.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "pack/composer": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

git@git.test.ua:bmp/composer.git - it's my repo, that containe next composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "pack/composer",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@git.test.ua:components/curl.git"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "pack/curl": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "pack\\composer\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

git@git.test.ua:components/curl.git - also my repo, that containe next composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "pack/curl",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "pack\\curl\\": ""
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

When I try to do composer install on my project, I receive next error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for pack/composer dev-master -> satisfiable by pack/composer[dev-master].
- pack/composer dev-master requires pack/curl dev-master -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

I already add param:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

If I remove require section from the seckond composer.json file the no error any more.

```
"pack/curl": "dev-master"
```

How fix it, I need this require?

---

**Update:**

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {"type": "vcs", "url": "https://git.test.ua/components/composer.git"},
        {"type": "vcs", "url": "https://git.test.ua/components/curl.git"}
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "pack/composer": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

---

```
Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing pack/composer (dev-master 886d220)
Cloning 886d22082d4aa341731ebd87f280ee0f5a05fe37

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

---

**Update2** composer.lock file

```
{
    "_readme": [
        "This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state",
        "Read more about it at http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file",
        "This file is @generated automatically"
    ],
    "hash": "cc5c1fc7000544f6cfd9ba03a3ee4567",
    "packages": [],
    "packages-dev": [
        {
            "name": "pack/composer",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://git.test.ua/components/composer.git",
                "reference": "886d22082d4aa341731ebd87f280ee0f5a05fe37"
            },
            "require-dev": {
                "pack/curl": "dev-master"
            },
            "type": "library",
            "autoload": {
                "psr-4": {
                    "pack\\composer\\": ""
                }
            },
            "time": "2015-04-24 07:13:31"
        }
    ],
    "aliases": [],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "stability-flags": {
        "pack/composer": 20
    },
    "prefer-stable": false,
    "prefer-lowest": false,
    "platform": [],
    "platform-dev": []
}
```

Comment: If I try to make composer install from the seckond composer.json file it will be ok. But it's not work with the first file.

Comment: is pack/technical_session == pack/technical ?

Comment: It's my mistake when I copy code here. Fix it, problem still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Composer does not browse repositories recursively, i.e. ALL repositories that may contain software have to be mentioned in the root `composer.json` file.

You don't mention the repository of the pack/curl package there, so Composer cannot find this package.

I assume that "pack" is the vendor name you added partially in your question, because the error message still mentions "shkarbatov" as the vendor name.

Best way to avoid having to add hundreds of personal repositories everywhere is to have a packagist-like Composer repo that is mentioned everywhere and contains the metadata of all code repositories. Have a look at [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis).

**Update:**

Now after seeing your composer.lock file, the situation is clear: You are NOT using `require` to add your packages, but `require-dev`. This is for development dependencies (like adding PHPUnit or stuff needed to develop the package) of the root package only - any dev dependencies of packages added to the root package are NOT installed.

Change the dependencies of packages you need for production use to `require` all levels!

Comment: About shkarbatov as vendor name it was my mistake when I copy code here, fixed it.

Comment: Trying to add all repositories in my composer.json file, but it's not help. No errors but composer download only first package.

Comment: If composer doesn't find stuff, it won't install anything. If it installs one package, then it works successfully. The absence of error messages proves that. Note that you might have had the repository of the one package cloned already. For a fresh start: Delete the `vendor` folder (be careful not to delete work you want to keep) and run `composer update` again. It should clone/download every package you need, and list it.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I remove vendor folder, and than run composer update, but it download only one package.

Comment: Can you add the modified `composer.json` and the result of the update run to your question, please?

Comment: Update data, you can see it above.

Comment: I suspect that the "pack/composer" does not need anything else in the commit that gets installed. Can you add the created `composer.lock` file as well? It should contain the relevant metadata from all required packages.

Comment: Add composer.lock file in Update2, you can see it above.